# How to find the latest date from each group created with Group-Object

Tags: powershell

I have an array of custom objects with 3 properties total.

```
PS> $aOutput | select -first 10 | ft -auto

MifProblem    FileCreationTime      Client
----------    ----------------      ------
dataldr.box   12/2/2013 9:45:50 AM  UAPURO1-NURSE1
DeltaMismatch 11/25/2013 7:01:37 AM UAPISTRAINING3
DeltaMismatch 11/23/2013 2:52:21 AM PICASO-2123
DeltaMismatch 11/24/2013 7:16:40 AM JADE05
DeltaMismatch 11/29/2013 8:21:10 AM JADE05
DeltaMismatch 11/19/2013 6:31:09 AM JADE05
DeltaMismatch 12/1/2013 5:25:41 AM  JADE05
DeltaMismatch 11/20/2013 5:40:33 AM JADE05
DeltaMismatch 11/18/2013 8:05:43 AM JADE05
DeltaMismatch 11/21/2013 8:30:45 AM JADE05
```

I'm trying to find out how I can group this array by the client with a count of all MifProblem and the latest FileCreationtime.

Here's the output I'd like to see based on the array above:

```
Client         MifProblems LatestFileCreationTime
------         ----------- ----------------------
UAPURO1-NURSE1 1           12/2/2013 9:45:50 AM
UAPISTRAININ3  1           11/25/2013 7:01:37 AM
PICASO-2123    1           11/23/2013 2:52:21 AM
JADE05         7           12/1/2013 5:25:41 AM
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$aOutput | group Client | 
select Count,Name,@{n='Client';e={$_.Group | sort FileCreationTime | select -l 1 -exp FileCreationTime }}
```

Comment: Use `sort -Desc` or `select -Last 1`, otherwise you'd select the oldest rather than the latest (i.e. newest) file.

Comment: I used it that way because it matched the requested output of the OP.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Check the result for the last client (JADE05).

Comment: I copied the output (first 10 items) and modified it as here-string (content is comma separated, then piped to: ConvertFrom-Csv | group Client | select Count,Name,@{n='Client...  I get the same result as the desired output of the OP.

Comment: I don't see how that could possibly work. Default sort order is ascending, so `12/1/2013 5:25:41 AM` should come out *last*, even without converting the field to a date (and it does for me, see [here](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sort_filecreationtime.shtml)).

Comment: You're right, my bad! I can see now where I was wrong, I guess I only briefly checked the first 3 dates and assumed that the fourth is accurate too. I changed it to -Last. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use hash tables as accumulators
(not tested, requires V3)

```
$MIFProblem_ht = @{}
$LastCreate_ht = @{}

$aOutput |
 foreach {
   $MIFProblem_ht[$_.client]++
   if ($_.FileCreationTime -gt $LastCreate_ht[$_.client])
     {$LastCreate_ht[$_.client] = $_.FileCreationTime}
   }

$MIFProblem_ht.keys |
 foreach { [PSCustomObject]@{
   Client = $_
   MifProblems = $MIFProblem_ht[$_]
   LastFileCreationTime = $LasCreate_ht[$_]
  }
```